# Working with low res images Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, resolution

I have to create a 4-banner wide roll-up design, but all I have to work with is a 1500px wide image. If I resize this, so it fits the banners, it becomes, logically, very pixelated. I have taken a look at [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5204/photoshop-a-low-res-image-to-make-it-appear-higher-res), but the result (after importing it in Illustrator) looks quite blurry.

This is why I'm wondering if there is a function or trick in Illustrator to blow up a picture, without it looking like crap. Of course it doesn't have to look like it's not resized, but it should be good enough to take pictures in front of.

The image I'm working with is [this one](http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140430005656/esbjerg/images/b/b7/Download_(2).jpg).

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic trick to transform a low resolution photo to a high res image without losing sharpness. If you're willing to let your photo have a more stylized look there are some options. There are some solutions using Photoshop but since you're in Illustrator I would look into the Image Trace function.

I did a quick test by opening up your image in Illustrator and using Image Trace with the 'High Fidelity Photo' settings. This will vectorize your image, allowing you to enlarge it without losing sharpness . But it'll at the same time simplify your image giving it sort of a watercolor feel to it. See example below with your original to the left and the vectorized image to the right.

At a distance it'll look a lot like your photograph but up close you'll see the simplified details: [View larger here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KtK8.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very easy solution!

First open your file in Photoshop and under Image Size, **uncheck** resample image. Beside resolution field, put in 300. Hit, OK. The file will resize itself to a smaller measurement but it will be 300 dpi.  (Same pixel size, just smaller in inches.) Save it as a jpg.

Now, open Illustrator. Go up to File, down to `place`, and place your new image. Just click somewhere on your file. Go up to the top, Just **beside** the button that says, Live Trace, hit the little arrow. A popup menu will appear and go all the way down to `Tracing options`.

`Tracing options` menu will pop up and you need to change a few things on here. Under Adjustments, Mode: Choose Color, Max Colors: 108 or so, 
Next Column: Check file, Uncheck Stroke, Path Fitting:0, Minimum area: 0, Corner Angle:0. Check Ignore White.

Now Hit Trace Button. Your result should be perfect. If you're happy with it, hit the `Expand` button at the top. **Save you file and name it**. Size it with the proportion tool to any size you need. You will not loose any resolution no matter what size you make it.

Voila! Solved!

Comment: No advertising please.